# stackoverflow.email incorrectly capitalises link as StackOverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, trademark, capitalization

At the top of [stackoverflow.email](https://stackoverflow.email), there is a link to Stack Overflow, however the link is shown as ‘StackOverflow.com’.

> [image]

However, this capitalisation is incorrect, based on the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

> The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply).

Could the link be corrected so that the capitalisation is correct?

Comment: Rather correct the trademark guidelines. It’s a proper name; I as a reader expect it to be capitalised.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "Stack Overflow" is the proper name, with a space and capitalisation. The domain name is a single word and IMO looks weird capitalised.

Comment: The domain name is also a proper name. (I do not care about Camel case, just about the initial *S.*)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "Stackoverflow.com"? That's even more peculiar and unlike the actual site name!

Comment: How about removing `.com`?

Comment: @Pandya An alternative would be to replace the domain name with the name of the site, indeed, but removing ‘.com’ wouldn't be enough — ‘Stack Overflow’ has a space.

Comment: @grgarside oh! Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops, thank you very much for pointing this out. [Update should be live now](https://email.stackoverflow.com/).

[image]

Comment: I don't find it fixed yet.

Comment: Where did my comments with ale go from the question?

Comment: @grgarside comments are often removed when they become a discussion (by moderators, after being flagged). If there was anything useful in the comments, it should be edited into the post, or posted as new answer. (generally speaking, don't know what you discussed.)

Comment: @Sha Yeah I get that, but ale explained their reason for downvoting my question, to which I replied, then ale deleted their comment, seems a bit odd that later on my replies would be removed too — they weren't specifically applying to that user. Guess I'll see about finding those links I used in my comment again.

Comment: @grgarside comments are very volatile, they can be removed any second, because many users consider all comments as noise and flag them all. Personally I don't like it, but that's how things work in SE for long time.

Comment: @Ted This still isn't fixed, 2 days of caching?

Comment: @grgarside Hmm, fixed on Friday. With time zones, might not have made it live before the weekend hit. Checking now.

Comment: @grgarside [update should be live now](https://email.stackoverflow.com/), sorry about the delay and thanks again for pointing this out.